# Getting only the specific values from dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to get only the "code" value from my dictionary, but not sure i am doing it right. Ideally my out put should be only code

```
peq = {
'sg':{'code':9, 'perror':0},
'6e':{'code':17, 'perror':0},
'g8':{'code':25, 'perror':0},
'i7':{'code':33, 'perror':0},
'9h':{'code':41, 'perror':0},
'it':{'code':49, 'perror':0},
'ic':{'code':57, 'perror':0},
'9w':{'code':65, 'perror':0},
's2':{'code':73, 'perror':0},
'ai':{'code':81, 'perror':0}
}



for the_value['code'], in peq.iteritems():
    print the_value
```

Comment: What do you mean you're not sure? Does it work or not?

Comment: `print the_value['code']` instead of `print the_value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should iterate over the values in this case:

```
for value in peq.itervalues():
    print value['code']
```

You can also go through the items, but that returns tuples of key/value pairs, where the value is each internal dictionary instance:

```
for key, value in peq.iteritems():
    print value['code']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for key in peq:
        print peq[key]['code']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach that will return all 'code' values as a list:

```
map(lambda x: x['code'], peq.values())
```

Result of this will be:

```
[41, 65, 17, 81, 73, 57, 9, 49, 33, 25]
```

Obviously you can iterate over that:

```
for i in map(lambda x: x['code'], peq.values()):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

try pandas, it can do more than you can imagine

```
In [16]: peq = {
   ....: 'sg':{'code':9, 'perror':0},
   ....: '6e':{'code':17, 'perror':0},
   ....: 'g8':{'code':25, 'perror':0},
   ....: 'i7':{'code':33, 'perror':0},
   ....: '9h':{'code':41, 'perror':0},
   ....: 'it':{'code':49, 'perror':0},
   ....: 'ic':{'code':57, 'perror':0},
   ....: '9w':{'code':65, 'perror':0},
   ....: 's2':{'code':73, 'perror':0},
   ....: 'ai':{'code':81, 'perror':0}
   ....: }

In [17]: import pandas as pd

In [18]: data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(peq)

In [19]: data
Out[19]:
        6e  9h  9w  ai  g8  i7  ic  it  s2  sg
code    17  41  65  81  25  33  57  49  73   9
perror   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

In [20]: data.iloc[0]
Out[20]:
6e    17
9h    41
9w    65
ai    81
g8    25
i7    33
ic    57
it    49
s2    73
sg     9
Name: code, dtype: int64

In [21]:
```

some intro of pandas

1. [[pandas intro 1]](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/litaotao/data-science/blob/master/examples/Pandas%20DataFrame%20%E8%AF%A6%E8%A7%A3%E4%B9%8B1%20%EF%BC%8D%20%E6%9E%84%E5%BB%BA%20%20DataFrame.ipynb)
2. [[pandas 10 minutes]](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html)

Comment: @PeterWood I assume that the question is a sub-sub-*-sub problem of the real use case of the author.